# MySql ERROR 1064 -restoring database

Tags: mysql

HELP. I am not sure how to fix this error. I am trying to restore a MySql database that was given to me. But I get the following error message.

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 29: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 6

```
`-- MySQL Administrator dump 1.4
--
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   4.0.27-nt


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;


--
-- Create schema aircraftmanager
--

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS aircraftmanager;
USE aircraftmanager;

--
-- Definition of table `addump`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `addump`;
CREATE TABLE `addump` (
  `ADID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ADNO` varchar(175) default NULL,
  `AIRCRAFTID` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ADID`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the create table syntax for 5.1 SQL I do not see a TYPE value that is valid.  Given that this suggests the storage engine to use then you should use

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `addump`;
CREATE TABLE `addump` (
  `ADID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ADNO` varchar(175) default NULL,
  `AIRCRAFTID` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ADID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engine-setting.html - for engine part
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html - for syntax

Comment: Sorry..this might seem like a stupid question...I need to change the "Type=MyISAM" to "ENGINE=MyISAM"...right...So I opened the .sql file in Wordpad and made the change and I tried saving it, but word keeps crashing...Any idea what I am doing wrong???

Comment: No idea.  Given that I have no idea then my "best" suggestion is to open it with notepad or another text editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS aircraftmanager;
USE aircraftmanager;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS addump;
CREATE TABLE addump (
  ADID int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ADNO varchar(175) default NULL,
  AIRCRAFTID int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (ADID)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

this should work

Comment: You omitted the `ENGINE`

Comment: sorry I forgot the ENGINE well spotted

Comment: so I need to remove all the single quotes after CREATE TABLE

Comment: are you only dealing with only  MYSQL or are you combining  with other languages. normally single quotes are  used to insert values for example  varchar  and numbers do not require single quotes when insert value to a table..   this is what I mean >>>  INSERT INTO addump (ADID, ADNO,AIRCRAFTID) VALUES(1225, 'TEXT GOES HERER',121)
use this website http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp it helps with examples and so on...